# R coding: creating a name variable to use with select

Tags: r

I am wondering if this is correct:

```
VAR <- c("City")
data %>% 
  select(salary, age, VAR)
  melt(id.vars = c("Salary2", "Age2","City")) -> finalData
```

I get the message:

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
ℹ Use `all_of(VAR)` instead of `VAR` to silence this message.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
```

The resulting finalData seems correct, but I wonder if this is the way to go.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Like the error says, use `all_of` (imported by `tidyverse` from `tidyselect`):

```r
var <- "Sepal.Length"
iris %>% 
  select(tidyselect::all_of(var)) %>% 
  str

# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
```

**Rationale**

Let's say we want to select a column:

```r
iris[, "Sepal.Length"]
```

In base R, we can easily select columns with variables:

```r
var <- "Sepal.Length"
iris[, var]
```

---

However, you are using `tidyverse` functions. For example, `select` is from the `dplyr` package. The `tidyverse` packages rely on a special type of [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). As such, the correct way of selecting the `"Sepal.Length"` column is:

```r
select(iris, Sepal.Length) 

# more typically written as:
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length)
```

As you can see, we are no longer using quotation marks. This is similar to `iris$Sepal.Length` in base R. A more extensive explanation of design choices in `dplyr` can be found [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). The core reasons for designing `tidyverse` this way are that it is more intuitive to use, and that is often faster to write.

---

Let's consider your case:

```r
VAR <- c("City")
iris %>% select(VAR)
```

What it is doing, is looking for `"VAR"` inside `iris`. Since it cannot find it, it will then evaluate `VAR`, which yield `"City"`. It will then look for `"City"`, which in this case it won't find. It does work if we specify a column that is present (like in your example):

```r
VAR <- c("Sepal.Length")
iris %>% select(VAR)
```

---

**Where it goes wrong**

So, what happens if we have a column called `VAR`, and supply a variable called `VAR`?

```r
iris$VAR <- 1
VAR <- c("Sepal.Length")
iris %>% select(VAR) %>% str

#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ VAR: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Here, it will return the column with ones, NOT what we intended. Using `all_of`, we can explicitly indicate that `select` should consider an EXTERNAL variable. This is to ensure that you get the results that you expect:

```r
iris$VAR <- 1
VAR <- c("Sepal.Length")
iris %>% select(all_of(VAR)) %>% str

#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I got confused as to which package I am using. I use the select function, from dplyr, not tidyverse. So It should work in my case. Also, in my case VAR is not the name of any column, its value is.

Comment: `dplyr` is part of `tidyverse`. If you type `?select`, you'll find that `dplyr` actually imports `select` from `tidyselect` :)

Comment: And I realise that `VAR` is not one of your columns. The point I was making is that it is dangerous not to use `all_of( )` because one of your columns may have the same name. Using `all_of( )` ensures that your code behaves as you expect it to. It is safer to include it, although in your specific example it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the VAR created another instance that is not part of data. Remember in R, everything is a vector.

Comment: Thanks. How to create a variable that can replace tens of others one so I don't have to replace manually?

Comment: This answer is not correct; running `select(VAR)` doesn't create anything. It just happens to evaluate `VAR` (since the column `"VAR"` is not present) to then run `select(City)`, which is a column in the original dataset. If it had not been a column, it would give an error.

Comment: Thanks! now I too have got it cleared.

Comment: Not everything in R is a vector. For example, functions aren't.